# my dotnet application doesn't run on windows server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-server-2003

I've written a server programm lets call it progie , this progie working just like a clock on my windows 7 (my ms VS is installed on windows 7) after compiling the progie and transfer it to windows server 2003 I tried to run the progie but no chance.

here is the symptom :

when i was trying to run the progie I was also monitoring the task manager , in task manager it shows the progie for only couple of seconds and then the poor program vanishes from the task manager or its better to say from the memory.

I'm using .net 3.5 / C# 
libraries : generics , diagnostic , IO

installed frameworks on my server :
dotnetfx 2.0
dotnetfx 3.0
dotnetfx 3.5

windows server 2003

Comment: What kind of program is *progie*? Is it an executable, a web application, a web site or something else? Does it rely on features added in .NET 3.5 SP1, and if so, have you installed .NET 3.5 SP1 on the server?

Comment: Also, was any exception thrown when you started the application?

Comment: I think progie support was added in Windows 2008.

Comment: Is progie using threads? Sounds like it jumped off into the woods somehow...was it relying on win 7 specific features? You should edit your question again and fill in more details that we are asking you for! :)

Comment: there is no exception , its .net 3.5 not 3.5sp1 , i just use the process library I haven't use any thread yet , my progie is desktop based but it vanished without any reason. :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your progie runs fine on Windows 7 with VS installed and fails on the server. Possible causes can be,

1. progie depends on third party libraries, which you did not yet install on the server. Things like DevExpress libraries and so on will lead to such problems. The fix is to deploy the dependencies along with your executable.
2. Your code raises unhandled exception on server 2003. If so, you should be able to find crash records for progie in Application event log. The fix is to capture crash dump and analyze it. http://dumpanalysis.org

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't even crash, just vanishes, it sounds to me like a .Net FW mismatch (i.e. you're missing the right version) or another missing resource. Easiest way to get a hold of this: download SysInternals' ProcMon, and monitor which files/DLLs progie tries to open and fails. That should put you on the right track.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy: Well...the OP clearly stated that the versions of framework was installed on the server....hence -1....

Comment: @tommieb75 it could still be a version discrepency. Nevertheless, the solution I offered is quite general and will address other resource issues as well.